# deg of $f$ is well defined

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, differential-topology

I was reading Guillemin & Pollack differential topology book, there is a corollary in page 115 that I can't work it out:

Corollary. If $\operatorname{dim} X=\operatorname{dim} Y$ and $Y$ is connected, then $I(f,\{y\})$ is the same for every $y \in Y$. Thus $\operatorname{deg}(f)$ is well defined.

Proof. Since $Y$ is connected, **the inclusion maps $i_{0}, i_{1}$ of any two points $y_{0}, y_{1} \in Y$ are homotopic.** Therefore
$$
I\left(f,\left\{y_{0}\right\}\right)=I\left(f, i_{0}\right)=I\left(f, i_{1}\right)=I\left(f,\left\{y_{1}\right\}\right) . \quad 
$$

---

The question is why the inclusion maps $i_{0}:\{y_0\}\to Y, i_{1}:\{y_1\}\to Y$ of any two points $y_{0}, y_{1} \in Y$ are homotopic.The prolem is the domain of the map are even different how to construct a homotopy ?I know there is a Homogeneity lemma, which says there is a diffeomorphism of $Y$ which sends $y_0 \to y_1$ that isotopic to the identity, does this statement says this?

Comment: I guess $Y$ is path connected?

Comment: that's not so important? $Y$ is path-connected is the same as connected ?The question is why $i_0$ homotopic to $i_1$ they have different domain? @
Arctic Char

Comment: Well, may you can just write $i_0, i_1$ as mapping from the same domain $\{pt\}$.

Comment: ah, I see , thank you